# How Do I Insert Tab Bar Controller Into Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, tabs, storyboard, uitabbar

I have an existing iPhone application that consists of a Login VC, Account Table VC, and an Account Detail VC. Note this storyboard:[image]

I need to enhance the Account Detail VC to show a tab bar that would allow the surfacing of other information related to the selected account like recent orders, map, etc. What I've done so far is to embed the Account Detail VC in a Tab Bar Controller like this:

[image]

It's not clear to me how to wire up the new Tab Bar Controller into the existing Storyboard. Most examples I see on the use of the Tab Bar Controller have it as the root VC; this is clearly not the case here as I want tabs present only on the Account Detail view (and the other tab sibling views as well - not shown here).

Thanks much everyone for your assistance.

Comment: You insert the Tab bar controller any where. connect Account Table VC to Tab bar controller through segue and connect as many as VC's for the Tab bar controller based on your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to add a push segue from your table view controller (or from a cell) to the tab bar controller. The AccountDetailView should be connected to the tab bar controller with a "relationship segue" ---> viewControllers.

Comment: Thanks you @rdelmar. Worked perfectly after I tweaked my prepareForSeque method.